# Multiple authentication and user redirects in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a column in my users table named `role` which stores the use type for each registered user. I want to route each type of user to a different dashboard upon successful registration.
this is routes for the dashboards

```
//Dashboards
Route::get('/operations', 'HomeController@operations')->name('operations')->middleware('verified'); //Operations dashboard
Route::get('/clients', 'HomeController@clients')->name('clients')->middleware('verified'); //clients dashboard
Route::get('/humanResource', 'HomeController@humanResource')->name('humanResource')->middleware('verified'); //HR dashboard
```

This is the `HomeController`

```
public function operations()
{

    if(Auth::user()->role == 'Operations'){

        return view('operations');

    }else{
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}

public function clients()
{

    if(Auth::user()->role == 'Client'){

        return view('clients');

    }else{
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}


public function humanResource()
{

    if(Auth::user()->role == 'Human Resource Manager'){

        return view('humanResource');

    }else{
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

This is my `RegisterController`

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    // User role
    $role = Auth::user()->role;

    // Check user role
    switch ($role) {
        case 'Operations':
            return '/operations';
            break;

        case 'Client':
            return '/clients';
            break;


        case 'Human Resource Manager':
            return '/humanResource';
            break;

        default:
            return '/login';
            break;
    }
}
```

I also added the above code to my `VerificationController.php`, `LoginController.php`, and `ResetPasswordController`
This is my `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`

```
// protected $redirectTo = '/home';

public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

        // return redirect('/home');

        function redirectTo()
        {
            // User role
            $role = Auth::user()->role;

            // Check user role
            switch ($role) {
                case 'Operations':
                    return '/operations';
                    break;

                case 'Client':
                    return '/clients';
                    break;

                case 'Human Resource Manager':
                    return '/humanResource';
                    break;

                default:
                    return '/login';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Currently, the code works fine if I register a user as `Operations` but if I try registering a user as `Client` or `Human Resource Manager`, it redirects me back to the login page after the email verification. If I check the database, I will see that the user was created. If I try logging in with the details of the `Client`, It will redirect me to the login page and also shows the username of the `Client` in the navbar (meaning that the user is successfully logged in but it can't find his dashboard). Am guessing the problem is from my `Switch-case` statement...it only works for the first case i.e operations.

Comment: I tried your `switch` code and works fine. For me the problem is with the roles names, remember that the `switch` are case sensitive when comparing `strings`, are you sure that the roles names are correct in your DB??

Comment: Yes...I have checked and its the same...I was using this condition before on the view to display the different users..but as the user types grew to three, I decided put them on different dashboards

Comment: Am also wondering if there is another file I need to modify

Comment: What is `$user->role` ? An attribute or database field? Do you also have a relation called `public function role() { return hasOne(Role::class);}` ?

Comment: `role` is a column in the `users` table.

Comment: Problem seems to be in your Middleware `verified`, where it works normally for Client, then upon reverifying in the Middleware it fails because of Case Sensitivity maybe and then Redirect to Login. So the redirect to login might happen in `verified` Middleware instead of Controllers.

Comment: To debug it, you're gonna have remove some redirect and print something to see where you at, and each time you complete a step, add redirect to that step and remove redirect of the next step just to debug. Or Better, log everything that happen to a Log file and then go an see what happened correctly and what has not.

Comment: What is in the `verified` Middleware?

Comment: that's laravel's email verification , middleware

Comment: On verified failure, it redirects to Login? Are you sure that mail verification Middleware are not guilty sending an Auth Client to Login again?
Any way, try to Log to a file before each redirect and you will know exactly what happen

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging#writing-log-messages . Use like `Log::debug('RedirectIfAuthenticated - User role : '.$role);`, and access it in `storage/logs/laravel.log`. Or config a new Channel in `config/logging.php` to log them in a new file of your choice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189333/discussion-between-austin-and-keiteldog).